# 3D model to CNC (wood material) .dxf, .igs

Tags: export

I'm reading about preparing 3D model to CNC and I feel lost, because some info is old (maybe outdated?) or there are too many ways to produce finish file. I saw words like: FreeMill, CamBam, G-code, addon to export dxf...

I would like to create something like a bowl with hole. It should be created carefully using measurement. The CNC machine opens only 2 file extensions: .dxf, .igs.

My questions:

- Is it possible to do it with Blender or other free software?,
- Which option is the best to make one project(test),

I know my English isn't perfect :)
Regards

Comment: You are probably better off using some sort of CAD like software like FreeCAD or similar.

Comment: I heard about Design Spark Mechanical too. Do You know which will be better to get smooth areas(and similar to Blender/3ds max)? Next question is: which extension try to do .dxf or .igs and how?

Comment: IGS is a NURBS oriented file format, Blender can't export that as far as I know, DXF is a 2D and Solid modelling oriented file format, also supports meshes I think. Both formats should be fine. Never used Design Spark Mechanical, seems good.